# initializing many slick carousels in page

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am dynamically loading slick carousels into a page. I do not know the total slides available to each carousel. Hard coding it works fine, however, I would like it to dynamically change the "slidesToShow" setting to be at most 3. If it is 2 or 1 however, I would like it to return 1.

I am successfully using a loop to get each slider like so:

```
$(".carousel").each(function(index){
  //set each carousel/slider
  $(this).slick()....
})
```

I am able to get the total slides for each slider with init:

```
$(this).on("init", function(event, slick){
                    slidetoshowscroll = parseInt(slick.slideCount);
                    if(slidetoshowscroll > 3){
                        slidetoshowscroll = 3;
                    }
                    if(slidetoshowscroll < 3){
                        slidetoshowscroll = 1;
                    }
//shows the correct slide #s
                    console.log(slidetoshowscroll);

                })
```

This gives me 3,1,3 etc... as the sliders are initiated.

However, I am not able to set the dynamic "slidetoshowscroll" variable on the slider itself:

```
$(this).slick({
                    autoplay: false,
                    arrows: true,
                    infinite: false,
                    speed: 300,
                    slidesToShow: slidetoshowscroll,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

How can I dynamically let "slick" know how many slides I have to show for each slideshow?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calculating the initial children count upfront before creating the slick carousel, so that the `slidesToShow` option is set correctly right from the start, like so:

```
$(".carousel").each(function(index){
    var childrenCount = this.childElementCount;
    var slidetoshowscroll;
    if(slidetoshowscroll > 3){
        slidetoshowscroll = 3;
    }
    if(slidetoshowscroll < 3){
        slidetoshowscroll = 1;
    }
    $(this).slick({
        ...
        slidesToShow: slidetoshowscroll,
    })....
})
```

But if you insist on creating the carousel with default options, but you want to base your later calculations on slick.slideCount (which might, for some reason, be different than `childElementCount`), then you can modify the slick option using `slickSetOption`, like so:

```
$(this).on("init", function(event, slick){
    slidetoshowscroll = parseInt(slick.slideCount);
    if(slidetoshowscroll > 3){
        slidetoshowscroll = 3;
    }
    if(slidetoshowscroll < 3){
        slidetoshowscroll = 1;
    }
    slick.slick("slickSetOption", "slidesToShow", slidetoshowscroll, true);
})
```